# How can I pass the value of this from a .change to another function with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$("#cityID").change(cityIdChanged(this))


function cityIdChanged(select) {
   store.setItem('CityID', select.val());
}
```

This seems not to work as it gives me an error message saying that "select" does not support the property val.

How can I pass a reference to the thing that changed to my cityIdChanged function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#cityID").change(function(){
    cityIdChanged(this); // "this" is the DOM object
});


function cityIdChanged(select) {
   store.setItem('CityID', select.value); // You get value with .value not .val()
}
```

Don't use jQuery to get input value.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/KMYMA/)

---

#### Know Your DOM Properties and Functions

While one of the goals of jQuery is to abstract away the DOM, knowing DOM properties can be extremely useful. One of the most commonly made mistakes by those who learn jQuery without learning about the DOM is to [Utilize the awesome power of jQuery to access properties of an element](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element):

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src');  // Bad!
});
```

In the above code, `this` refers to the element from which the click event handler was fired. The code above is both slow and verbose; the code below functions identically and is much shorter, faster and readable.

```
$('img').click(function() {
    this.src; // Much, much better
});
```

[jQuery tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)

Comment: I tried var aaa = select.value; but this gives aaa as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cityID").change(cityIdChanged(this))


function cityIdChanged(select) {
   store.setItem('CityID', $(select).val()); or // select.value but not select.val()
}
```